# how to require servlets to provide implementation of a method java

Tags: java

Newbie to the industry here, I'm currently trying to develop a web application that handles different kinds of forms. Over the time of when I'm developing the web application I noticed that I'm adding a method to different servlets that handles similar but not the same functionalities , now knowing that at some point someone else may be looking/making changes to the system, I want to create a template for these servlets via abstract class so the system code stays consistent when adding new forms

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    SampleMethodName(request,response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    SampleMethodName(request,response);
}

private void SampleMethodName(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {/* do stuff */}
```

I want to create an abstract class as a template for these servlets but I can't since java servlets already extends an abstract class

```
public class SampleClassName extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

I feel like I need to change  the approach but i want to ask anyway

Comment: have them implement an interface, or have your abstract class extend the abstract class they now extend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in having an abstract class extending another abstract class. So your special class could look like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractSampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

  protected final void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    sampleMethodName(request, response);
  }

  protected abstract void sampleMethodName(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException;

}
```

That's it. Now make all implementors extend your new base class instead of `HttpServlet` directly. Some additional notes here:

- The `doGet` should be marked as `final`, so implementors do not accidentally overwrite it, thus bypassing your implementation.
- The abstract method must be `public` or `protected`, but cannot be `private` (as in your example).
- In Java, it is common practice to have method names start with a lowercase character.